# Help with css3 animations with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, css

I am in need of some help, i am trying to use css3 animations in conjunction with jQuery in order to create more fluid animations, my issue here is the animation works fine, but when the animation is finished, the element shoots back to its original size, how can i get it to animate to 0px width and stay at that size. My code looks like this below:

```
<style>

.element{
width:210px;
height:210px;
background-color:#000; 
}


    .box {
    -webkit-animation-name: BOX;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }




    @-webkit-keyframes BOX {
    from {
    width: 210px;
    }
    to {
    width: 0px;
    }
    }
</style>

<html>
<div class="element"></div>

$('.element').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('box');
});

</html>
```

Comment: If your production code looks anything like this code, you will be better off with CSS transitions. They are supported in Opera, Webkit and Firefox, and their syntax is more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width:0px;` to the box class.
You've only defined an animation, it needs the persistent property as well.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPK6B/).

Bonus: this now also hides your object in non-webkit browsers.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, thanks again, any idea if there is similar syntax for mozilla?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it without some Javascript.